# WCF Azure 403 error when running locally

Tags: wcf, azure, http-status-code-403

I'm stumped. There are several threads out there that reference a similar problem, but not the same one. I'm trying to get a simple WCF service up and running in Azure, but my problem is happening before I even deploy. I'm following this article:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy/

Which says to create your project, build the "Hello World" service interface and class, and then start your project locally. I get a 403 error when I try to start my project.

The only step I'm not following exactly is that I don't have a "Start Without Debugging" option (I'm using Visual Studio Express Web Developer), so I just push "Start Debugging."

Why would I get a 403 error on my own machine? I am running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: I had the same problem and the above fix worked for me, I'm new to this but suprised I had a problem as using VStudio 2010 wizard to set up WCF cloud service. Setting azure project as startup project did not cure the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away when I upgraded to VS 2010 Pro. I never fixed it on Express, but after upgrading the problem was gone ... I had the "Start without Debugging" option in the Pro edition, so I suspect that the problem may have been specific to Express.

Answer (score 2):

On the WebRole project right click on your .svc (Service1.svc) and choose "Set As Start Page" And then run the project. Make sure to do this on the WebRole project not the Azure Cloude Project.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Azure project the default project or is the WCF Web Role?  If it's the role itself, that may be your issue - it's trying to access the root of virtual directory containing the web service versus running the cloud app in the local emulator.  If you browse to http://127.0.0.1:81/Service1.svc in a new browser window do you still get the 403?

Comment: Hi Jim, I'm not sure, the problem went away after upgrading to VS 2010 Pro. Didn't have that option when I asked the question, but it may have been something with the capabilities of the different versions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems VS has lost the its project settings. Bring up "Properties" page on the web service in VS. Go to the "Debug" tab. Under Servers/Virtual Path: my configuration was set to just "/". Put the name of your server back in there "/Service1.svc" and it should work from the debugger now. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Derek. I don't have a debug tab in my properties ...  but the problem fixed itself after upgrading to VS 2010 Pro.